# Is it safe to use "apt-get autoremove"?

Tags: apt

Months ago i read a note like "not use autoremove because it break the meta package on Freya", is it safe to use now?

I have so many packages which are no longer needed.

EDIT:

Thank you so much quassy for editing my english btw:

```
I seguenti pacchetti sono stati installati automaticamente e non sono
più richiesti:   consolekit hexchat-common libck-connector0
libgranite1 libgrip0   libkeybinder-3.0-0 libpam-ck-connector
libvala-0.26-0 libzeitgeist-1.0-1   linux-headers-3.16.0-37
linux-headers-3.16.0-37-generic   linux-headers-3.16.0-40
linux-headers-3.16.0-40-generic   linux-headers-3.16.0-41
linux-headers-3.16.0-41-generic   linux-headers-3.16.0-43
linux-headers-3.16.0-43-generic   linux-image-3.16.0-40-generic
linux-image-3.16.0-41-generic   linux-image-3.16.0-43-generic
linux-image-extra-3.16.0-40-generic  
linux-image-extra-3.16.0-41-generic
linux-image-extra-3.16.0-43-generic   pastebinit plank-theme-pantheon
sbsigntool Usare "apt-get autoremove" per rimuoverli.
```

Comment: `apt-get autoremove` will show you a list of packages before it gets executed. If you want to be sure, edit your question and copy&paste the list here so we can check.

Comment: i did it, ty quassy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You should be able to safely run `apt-get autoremove`, but shouldn't usually need to.**

It's almost always a bad idea to run commands unless you explicitly understand what they do and how, including any output they post and decisions they ask you to make.

However, based on the list of packages you provided, I think executing the command would be safe. Initially there are a few older libraries, common dependencies likely superseded by newer, separately packaged versions, and old kernel versions, nothing to worry about unless you've start experiencing issues as a result of recent updates. Finally there is the old plank theme, which can be safely uninstalled since you aren't using it anymore.